# PHP Get output from executing a binary

Tags: php, multithreading, binary

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to do the following using php:

I have a website that uses php to display database information. Now,
I'd like to be able to implement another capability and that is I'd like to write a new php web page and launch a thread which executes a binary and have the output be displayed on the web page live (if possible).

I think I need to use ajax to be able to refresh the page in order to show "live output" in the page.

The problem I'm having is figuring out if I can launch a thread that executes a binary and display the output on the webpage. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: in `PHP` you can use `excec()`, to execute any executable file, check http://in1.php.net/function.exec, 
later you can create ajax thread to call your php at some time-interval

Comment: I will give this approach a try and see what results I get. If this works, then I will provide a detail solution and credit your for the approach. Thanks!

Comment: thanks... If u need any sample code don't hesitate to ask., just for the clarification please let me know os where your server is running..  :-) good luck..

Comment: Thanks for the support. I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using apache 2.2.22 web server.

Comment: I've added sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, use jquery plugin, to do ajax and load result of `script.php` to any section of your html page.

**script.php**

```
<?php
     echo exec('date'); //type command to be executed here.
?>
```

**page.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(executeScript,1000);
    });

    function executeScript(){
        $("#result").load("script.php");
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"> command result will come here.. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It will call `script.php` at every second and its result will be shown in `<div id="result"> </div>`

You can also use jQuery ajax [.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to pass some argument to script and get response accordingly.

Comment: Dude, I'm shaking you hand digitally! Thank you for your help. That is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this kind of thing is usually to execute the binary and disown it but have its output written to a file as it runs.

Then your ajax system literally downloads that text file for display.

Comment: If the other suggestion does not work, then I will try this approach as well and do the same thing.